# Properties of the relation R on the set of all real functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

So... I'm working on this and I'm supposed to figure out if each of these properties are pertinent. Can someone please help me? Thank you!

Properties:

1. Reflexive
2. Symmetric
3. Anti-Symmetric
4. Transitive
5. Equivalence Relation
6. Partially Ordered Set

These are the problems where I need to address the above issues:

1. The relation $R$ on the set of all real function $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}^+$ where $f R g \iff f(n) = O(g(n))$. My answers are: 1. No 2. No 3. Yes 4. Yes. 5. No. 6. No.
2. The relation $R$ on the set of all real function $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}^+$ where $f R g \iff f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$. My answers are: 1. No 2. Yes 3. No 4. Yes 5. No 6. No.

Can you check my answers? I'm sorry but I'm not very good at this!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the notation, could you please explain $O(g(n))$ and $\Theta(g(n))$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\def\R{\mathrel R}R_1$ with $f \R_1 g$ iff $f \in O(g)$ we have

- $R_1$ is reflexive, as for any $f$ we have $|f| \le |f|$, hence $f \in O(f)$
- $R_1$ is not symmetric, since $n \in O(n^2)$, but $n^2 \not\in O(n)$.
- $R_1$ is not anti-symmetric, as $n \in O(n+1)$ and $n+1 \in O(n)$, but $n+1 \ne n$.
- $R_1$ is transitive, as if $f \in O(g)$ and $g \in O(h)$, say $|f| \le c_1|g|$ for $n\ge N_1$ and $|g|\le c_2|h|$ for $n \ge N_2$, then $|f| \le c_1c_2|h|$ for $n\ge \max(N_1, N_2)$, so $f\in O(h)$.
- No, as $R_1$ isn't symmetric.
- No, as $R_1$ isn't anti-symmetric.

For $\def\R{\mathrel R}R_2$ with $f \R_2 g$ iff $f \in \Theta(g)$ we have

- $R_2$ is reflexive, as for any $f$ we have $|f| \le |f|$, hence $f \in \Theta(f)$
- $R_2$ is symmetric, as $f \in \Theta(g)$ iff $f \in O(g)$ and $g \in O(f)$, iff $g \in \Theta(f)$.
- $R_2$ is not anti-symmetric, as $n \in \Theta(n+1)$ and $n+1 \in \Theta(n)$, but $n+1 \ne n$.
- $R_2$ is transitive, as $R_1$ is transitive (and $f \R_2 g$ iff $f\R_1 g$ and $g\R_1 f$)
- Yes, as $R_2$ is reflexive, symmetric and transitive.
- No, as $R_2$ isn't anti-symmetric.

Comment: @Chrissy I noticed you're new to MSE, welcome! If a post answers your question mark it as so then, this closes the question so people in the future don't stumble upon it and try to answer it unnecessarily.

Comment: Okay, thank you for clarifying!